# Unable to access port remotely for AWS machine although security group appears to allow it

Tags: amazon-web-services, security-policy

I have used the spark

```
ec2/spark-ec2
```

script to launch an AWS cluster.  It was launched, I am able to ssh into the master node, and spark is running - notably including the web-ui at port 8080:

```
$ ps -ef | grep spark
root      3807     1  1 00:22 ?        00:00:08 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0/bin/java -cp  -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
                            org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master 
                           --ip ec2-xxx.amazonaws.com --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
```

Also: on the master itself it is possible to access the web-ui :

```
$ wget 10.140.187.xx:8080
--2015-07-25 00:44:17--  http://10.140.187.xx:8080/
Connecting to 10.140.187.xx:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 7379 (7.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

100%[================================================================================================================================>] 7,379       --.-K/s   in 0s

2015-07-25 00:44:17 (439 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [7379/7379]
```

Now on the AWS Security Groups side of the equation: here it is. Notice in particular: ports 8080-81 are included:

[image]

So then - why is is not possible to connect to this master remotely - via the spark url - http://10.140.187.xx:8080 ?  It just times out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I see - it was because the ip address reported by the ec2 machine is apparently not externally visible.  I need to use

```
 ec2-54-234-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Instead of

```
10.140.xx.xxx
```